# How to use import statement in react?

Tags: reactjs

how to use import statement to import functions from one component to other component.

Below is how the import statement is:

```
import Tool from '../Common';
import { ToolContextProvider } from '../Common';
```

This complaint of duplicate lines. So I have tried something like below,

```
import { ToolContextProvider, Tool} from '../Common';
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct. How can write this in one line.
Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I have previously answered similar question. Hope it gives you some insights. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265810/how-to-import-function-from-another-file-into-reactjs-component/62266112#62266112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `import` like this. Just combine both of them.

```
import Tool, { ToolContextProvider } from '../Common';
```

Answer (score 4):

basically there are two different type of export in javascript modules (also react included):

1. default export
2. named export

default export would be like :

```
// someFile.js
export default SomeComponent
```

named export would be like

```
// someFile.js
export SomeOtherComponent
```

importing them in other components for using them should be like:

```
// useCase.js
import SomeComponent from './someFile' // for default export 
import { SomeOtherComponent } from './someFile' // for named export 
import SomeComponent, { SomeOtherComponent } from './someFile' // for using both
```